# Rolling Motion in Loop-de-Loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I had a question as follows:

> A tennis ball is a hollow sphere with a thin wall. It is set rolling without slipping at 4.03 m/s on a horizontal section of a track as shown in Figure P10.64. It rolls around the inside of a vertical circular loop of radius r   45.0 cm. As the ball nears the bottom of the loop, the shape of the track deviates from a perfect circle so that the ball leaves the track at a point h 5 20.0 cm below the horizontal section.
>
> (a) Find the ball’s speed at the top of the loop.
>
> (b) Demonstrate that the ball will not fall from the track at the top of the loop.
>
> (c) Find the ball’s speed as it leaves the track at the bottom.
>
> [image]

Now i start with an energy approach; for an isolated system we have $\Delta K +\Delta U =0$ so expanding it gives thhe following:
$$(\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_i^2)+(\frac{1}{2}I(\omega^2_f-\omega_i^2))+(mg(2r)-0)=0$$ considering the horizontal section as our reference line. After this step, the next line turns to
$$\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{3}mr^2)(\frac{v_f^2}{r^2})=\frac{1}{2}(mv_i^2+\frac{2}{3}mr^2(\frac{v_i^2}{r^2}))-2mgr$$

now i dont get why we used $I=\frac{2}{3}mr^2$ for the moment of inertia(MOI) as it is; shouldnt we use the parallel axis theorem to convert the (MOI) about the shell's center of mass to the MOI about the centre of the loop? Why are we able to use r, radius of loop, as the radius in calculating MOI?

Comment: I don't think that r represents the radius of the loop. Since we are using Iw^2 as the rotational energy, w is the angular velocity of the tennis ball about its centre, so r has to be the radius of the ball.

Comment: but then i am only given r for the loop, do i consider the ball to be a point mass then? that way using $I=\Sigma Mr^2$ works where r would be distance of said mass from the rotational axis passing through the center of loop

Comment: $I=2/3mr^2$ is *for sure* the MOI for a 'shell' = hollow sphere = the tennis ball. If they don't give you $r$ of the ball, it's impossible.

Comment: Now I am confused. I don't get what I should do now

Comment: @FarhanNoor It's a poorly defined question, with an element of trickery. Lacking the radius of the tennis ball, you have no choice but to consider it a point mass.It then becomes an extremely simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (well known) theorem of rotation states that the motion of any point on a rigid body can be expressed as a combination of motion and rotation: $$\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}_{CM} + \mathbf{ω} \times \mathbf{r}_{CM}$$ where $\mathbf{v}_{CM}$ is the velocity of the center of mass and $\mathbf{r}_{CM}$ is the vector from the center of mass to the point. By computing the integral $$\frac 12 \int \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} \text{d}m$$ it can be shown that the kinetic energy is equal to $\frac 12 \left(mv^2 + I_{CM} \omega^2\right)$, where $I_{CM}$ is the moment of inertia about the center of mass.

If we decide to use the parallel axis theorem to take the moment of inertia about a new axis, we are assuming that the ball is tidally locked to the new axis. In other words, the ball now behaves like a lollipop. It is both spinning about its own (center of mass) axis and orbiting around the new axis with the same angular velocity (just like the Moon), and this is in general not the case. In the context of the question, the radius of the ball appears to be much smaller than the radius of the loop, and thus the ball would spin much faster than it orbits around the loop.

I believe that the question is assuming that the ball is a point mass.